# Casting issue on calling the method of having javascript function

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My test class is getting failed when i calling the method from another class which contains the javascript function.

Problem in casting. The java script method from separate class is given below

```
public long javatimeout(WebDriver driver)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js =  (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    long loadTime = (long) js.executeScript(
                "return (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000");
    System.out.println("Screen Loading time is " +loadTime);
    return loadTime;

}
```

Inside the test class, calling the method "javatimeout" inside the method login.

```
`public class TC01login {

WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;

Commonclass obj1 = new Commonclass();

public void login()
{
    driver.get("https://staging.agshealth.com/NexGenQMS/#/upload");

    long timetaken = obj1.javatimeout(driver);
    System.out.println(timetaken);
}`
```

FAILED: login
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cast to `(long)` is in error.

According the docs, when a decimal value is returned from the javascript code then `JavascriptExecutor` returns a Double:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

A long is returned when a non-decimal value is returned from the Javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that the method executeScript returns a `java.lang.Double` value... You can't cast a `java.lang.Double` object to a `java.lang.Long` object! Try someting like this:

```
long loadTime = js.executeScript(...).longValue();
```

Or make sure that JS returns an integer instead of a double value!
For more information see [JavascriptExecutor#executeScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).
A more secure way would be something like this:

```
long loadTime;
Object returnObject = js.executeScript(...);

if(returnObject instanceof Number)
{
    loadTime = ((Number) returnObject).longValue();
}
```